# RavenDB index to return most recent entry

Tags: c#, mapreduce, ravendb

I am new to RavenDB and I am trying to query the document model below with the index below.  The index is almost working as desired, except now I need to only include the most recent status for a date in the total.  For example, a client could have multiple import statuses for a date, but only the last status should be counted in the resulting totals.

```
public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<ImportStatusMessage> ImportStatuses { get; set; }
}

public class ImportStatusMessage
{
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public ImportStatus Status { get; set; }
}

public enum ImportStatus
{
    Complete,
    Running,
    Failed,
    Waiting,
    NoReport
}
```

I am using the following index:

```
public class Client_ImportSummaryByDate : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Client, ImportSummary>
{
    public Client_ImportSummaryByDate()
    {
        Map = clients => from client in clients
                       from status in client.ImportStatuses
                       select new
                           {
                               status.Status,
                               Date = status.TimeStamp.Date,
                               Count = 1
                           };

        Reduce = results => from result in results
                            group result by new { result.Status, result.Date }
                            into g
                            select new
                                {
                                    g.Key.Status,
                                    g.Key.Date,
                                    Count = g.Sum(x => x.Count)
                                };

    }
}

public class ImportSummary
{
    public ImportStatus Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Can this be accomplished with an index?  Do I need a different approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
from status in client.ImportStatuses
```

Consider:

```
let status = client.ImportStatuses.Last()
```

If they might be out of order in the list, you could do:

```
let status = client.ImportStatuses.OrderBy(x => x.TimeStamp).Last()
```

You could also use `First` instead of `Last` if they were so ordered that way.

Any of these would index just a single status per client.  If instead you mean that you want multiple status, but only the last on any given date, you could do:

```
Map = clients => clients.SelectMany(x => x.ImportStatuses, (x, y) => new {x.Id, y.Status, y.TimeStamp})
                        .GroupBy(x => new {x.Id, x.TimeStamp.Date})
                        .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.TimeStamp).Last())
                        .Select(x => new
                                     {
                                         x.Status,
                                         x.TimeStamp.Date,
                                         Count = 1
                                     });
```

All of this would be in the map part of the index, since the list is self-contained in each document.

Comment: I see where you are going, but the SelectMany() was complaining after adding .Last() because the lambda was no longer returning an IEnumerable.  I converted the SelectMany() to a Select() and it complied, but the index no longer produces any results.

Comment: I'll update shortly with tested code.  Quick question - did you typo the names in the question?  You can't have a class and enum both named `ImportStatus`.

Comment: Updated my answer with a map that works.  There seems to be a bug in raven though - I can't use the full linq syntax with this, nor can I merge the two select statements into one.  I will log that bug with the RavenDB team.  There's nothing wrong with this one though - but there are more compact forms of the expression that should work and don't.

Comment: Perfect!  Good job on catching that bug in the LINQ parsing as well.  Thanks!

Comment: And... the bug is fixed :)

Comment: @FitzchakYitzchaki - Amazing.  You have some crazy linq/ast skills! Thanks!

Comment: @Brantino - I'd still stick with the one that passed until Fitzchak's fixes make it into a stable release.